# ASCII to ANSI convertion does not work

Tags: character-encoding, conversion

Trying to convert an ASCII file to ANSI on Linux:

```bash
$ file -bi relocate.xml 
text/xml; charset=us-ascii
$ iconv -f us-ascii -t ms-ansi < relocate.xml | file -bi -
text/xml; charset=us-ascii
$ cat relocate.xml | recode us-ascii..ms-ansi | file -bi -
Request: ANSI_X3.4-1968..:libiconv:..CP1252
Shrunk to: ANSI_X3.4-1968..CP1252
text/xml; charset=us-ascii
```

I also tried other tools to infer the encoding and they all return the same result :

```bash
$ enca -L none relocate.xml ; echo "###" ; uchardet relocate.xml ; echo "###" ; encguess relocate.xml 
7bit ASCII characters
  CRLF line terminators
###
ASCII
###
relocate.xml    US-ASCII
```

As you can see, there is no error message from `iconv` nor from `recode` tools, but the final encoding is still `us-ascii`.

How can I convert it to ANSI ?

Comment: There's no standard meaning to "ANSI [character set]". What character set do you want to convert to?

Comment: Since it's an XML file, are you sure it isn't UTF-8? (If it isn't, the character set will be defined in the opening declaration.) And since it is XML, why do you need to convert it at all anyway?

Comment: And if the file only contains 7-bit ASCII characters, converting it to CP-1252 won’t make any difference.

Comment: @roaima Couldn't convert my file to UTF-8 either, maybe because it does not contain any accents/special characters. Windows 10 Sysprep rejected my `relocate.xml` file so I though the encoding was wrong.

Comment: @StephenKitt So, if a file contains only 7-bit ASCII characters, ASCII = ANSI = UTF-8, is this correct ?

Comment: @SebMa yes, that’s correct. To make sure this applies in your case, convert the file and compare the results (`cmp`).

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't need to contain accented or other special characters. This text here could be UTF-8. Does sysprep require UTF-16LE?

Comment: @roaima I have no idea. I think I will open another question regarding my Sysprep answer file on Superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the encoding you're converting to (ms-ansi = windows-1252) is a superset of the encoding you're converting from (ascii), `iconv` will just leave it as it is, because obviously there's nothing to be done.

Also, the "character set" of a file is not some kind of mandatory metadata, and the `file` utility is just **guessing**, using unreliable heuristics that fail ~20% of the time, what that may be.

Example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' '<a>' '<b>'{0..100000}'</b>' '<c></c>' '</a>' > /tmp/foo.xml 
$ file /tmp/foo.xml 
/tmp/foo.xml: XML 1.0 document, ASCII text
$ file -bi /tmp/foo.xml 
text/xml; charset=us-ascii
```

No, that file is a UTF-8 file, which also has the correct xml declaration.

---

From the comments:

> Windows 10 Sysprep rejected my `relocate.xml` file so I though the encoding was wrong.

Add it the correct xml declaration (`<?xml ... ?>` as above) and check with some xml validator if the xml syntax is OK.

Comment: I also tried other tools to infer the encoding : `enca`, `uchardet` and `encguess`. They returned the same result : `ASCII`.

Comment: And they were all right.

Comment: @Codvid-19 Thank a lot for your help. Regarding my Sysprep answer file, I'll open another question because it's a different subject.